# SPFx SPComponentLoader.loadCSS external css

Tags: css, spfx, sharepoint-framework

Im trying to put mapbox working on a spfx webpart. But having trouble with it when deploying the webpart to App Catalog
On gulp serve, it works ok
[image]

but when deployed to App Catalog it renders like this
[image]

It shows up a warning on console, that the .css was not loaded, and I can see that is not present on Network tab.

Im loading the css like this

```
protected onInit(): Promise<void> {
SPComponentLoader.loadCss('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.46.0/mapbox-gl.css');
return super.onInit();
}
```

Like the example shown here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/reference-third-party-css-styles

Comment: what does the warning message show ? Can you try it as `protected onInit(): Promise<void> { 
    SPComponentLoader.loadCss('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.46.0/mapbox-gl.css'); 
    return super.onInit(); 
  }`

Comment: That was the code i was using, the content editor replaced the <void>. Nevertheless we got to solve the issue, it wasn't just the css, even the js script wasn't being loaded on the package, we had to add the reference to the js file on  node_modules in the "externals" in the config.json. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got to solve the issue, it wasn't just the css, even the js script wasn't being included on the package, we had to add the reference to the js file on node_modules in the "externals" in the config.json.